# PostgreSQL Fuzzy Matching

Tags: regex, postgresql, fuzzy-search

I have 2 tables with the following fields:

- First Name
- Last Name
- Middle Name
- State
- Zip
- SSN
- DOB
- Phone

I am trying to find the records that match between the 2 tables and records that most likely matche but are not an exact match because of input error, missing data, variation of name spelling, etc...

Some of the data is missing.  But for all the data that is there, both tables have the same format / data type for each data element.

Ideally I would like some kind of weighting mechanism for the results.

Now if SSN is a direct match then we have a match.  But I would also like to take into account if there was a user input error and 2 digits were mixed up or something like that.

What are my options in PG?

Straight matching does an okay job if I run multiple variations (Examples).

- Social Match
- Last Name, DOB, Zip
- Last Name, DOB, State
- Last Name, First Name, DOB, ZIP

However I would love to be deploy a more complete solution and am searching for any tips on how to proceed.

Comment: Neil's post below sent me in the right direction.  I ended up using Fuzzy Looks through SQL server.  http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Integration+Services+%28SSIS%29/3105/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called [Probabilistic Record Linkage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_linkage) (actually it has several names).

The first thing you want to do is standardize each column's values so they are directly comparable. For example, dates should be in ISO format and trimmed.

### The Easy Way

Count the number of matching columns:

```
select
 n.id as needle_id,
 h.id as haystack_id,
 case when n.col1 = h.col1 then 1 else 0 end 
 + case when some_comparison_function(n.col2, h.col2) then 1 else 0 end
 + ...
 as relevance
from 
 needles n
join 
 haystack h -- haystack table could be the same as needles table
on  -- only compare rows where at least one column matches
 n.col1 = h.col1 
 or some_comparison_function(n.col2, h.col2)
 or ...
order by 
 relevance desc;
```

### The Harder but More Correct Way

This has been mathematically [proven](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse590q/04au/papers/Felligi69.pdf) to be optimal. It computes the weight of the columns for you based on how rare values are.

1. Pick the probability of two values that should be equal but are different. For example, two records should have the same SSN, but there was a typo. One minus this value is your `m-prob` (call it 99%).
2. For each column calculate the relative frequency of each value. This is your `u-prob`
3. For each potential match (needle.dob vs haystack.dob), calculate the odds ratio if they agree: `m-prob / u-prob`, or the odds ratio if they disagree: `(1 - m-prob) / (1 - u-prob)`
4. Multiply all the odds ratios to get the total odds
5. Calculate the probability of a match: `total_odds / (1 + total_odds)`
6. If probability exceeds threshold then match, else non match

Comment: Are there any modules or examples on how to implement "The Harder but More Correct Way"?  I don't want to totally re-invent the wheel with a custom solution.

Comment: R has a package https://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/recordlinkage/

Comment: Thanks for the link.  You definitely are pointing me in the right direction.  There has to be a package out there for either PG or SQL server that will get me 90% of the way there.  My solution doesn't need to be perfect just better than straight matching.  Interesting article: http://blog.melissadata.com/data-quality-authority/2010/10/record-linkage-and-fuzzy-matching-part-1.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the [`fuzzystrmatch`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/fuzzystrmatch.html) and/or [`pg_trgm`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html) modules are what you're looking for.

Comment: I came across these in my research.  However I am looking more for a way to implement these for a more complete solution.